JS script work in one of Thymeleaf template but doesn't in other
I'm developing a Spring Boot aplication with Thymeleaf, and in a Controller I have two GetMappings with differents url's routes returning the same template.
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/detalhes")
public class DetailsAltController {

    @Autowired
    private NotasRepository notasRepository;

    @Autowired
    private RespostaRepository respostaRepository;
    
    @GetMapping("/sefaz")
    public String detalheSefaz(@RequestParam("cnpjUser") String cnpjUser, @RequestParam("cnpjEmpresa") String cnpjEmpresa, @RequestParam("idAlt") Long idNota, Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("cnpjUser", cnpjUser);
        model.addAttribute("tipoAlt", "Alteração Sefaz");
        model.addAttribute("cnpjEmpresa", cnpjEmpresa);
        
        NotasModel nota = notasRepository.findById(idNota).get();
        NotasDto notaDto = new NotasDto(idNota, nota.getData(), nota.getSerie(), nota.getNomeEmitente(), nota.getSituacao(), nota.getValor(), cnpjEmpresa);
        model.addAttribute("nota", notaDto);
        model.addAttribute("mes", notaDto.data().getMonth());
    


        return "detalhes";

    }

    @GetMapping("/cndt")
    public String detalheCndt(@RequestParam("cnpjUser") String cnpjUser, @RequestParam("cnpjEmpresa") String cnpjEmpresa, @RequestParam("idAlt") Long idResp, Model model){

        model.addAttribute("cnpjUser", cnpjUser);
        model.addAttribute("tipoAlt", "Alteração Cndt");
        model.addAttribute("cnpjEmpresa", cnpjEmpresa);

        RespostaModel resp = respostaRepository.findById(idResp).get();
        RespostaDto respostaDto = new RespostaDto(resp.getStatus(), resp.getData(), resp.getNovo(), cnpjEmpresa);
        model.addAttribute("mes", resp.getData().getMonth());
        model.addAttribute("resp", respostaDto);

        
        return "detalhes";
    }
    
}

When I acess the first route the JS runs correctly, but when I acess the second it doesn't. Here is my html file.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Detalhes</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/detalhes.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/main.js}" defer></script>
    </head>

Why this is occuring, and how can I fix this?

The second JS script doesn't run correctly - but what does it do? What do you see? Any browser console errors? Any other unexpected behavior? Any Spring errors?

I'm using the JS to format some informations in my HTML. In the first GetMapping this is happening fine, but in the second this just doesn't happen. It's like there's no JS.

Suggestion: Put a console logging statement in the JavaScript. Then check the browser's console to see if the statement executes.
